# Google Apps Script の呼び出し回数や時間制限の確認方法は？

Tags: google-apps-script

スプレッドシートのスクリプトを、時間主導型トリガーで起動していますが、
コード的には問題ないのに、うまく動作していなかったことがありました。

Google Apps Script には呼び出し回数や時間に制限があるとのことで、
この制限に掛かっているのではないかと疑っております。
　https://docs.google.com/a/macros/fourmix.co.jp/dashboard
　https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

１．これら制限のうちどの程度まで使用しているか、またはこの制限に掛かっているか
　を確認する方法（API）／一覧確認できるページ はあるでしょうか？

２．１日あたりの回数や時間で制限されているものについて、
　何時を基準に１日になるものでしょうか？
　JST（日本時間で 00:00でリセット）なのか？ GMT（日本時間で 09:00でリセット）なのか？等

３．例えば、Triggers total runtime が 6 hr / day を超えた場合について、
　手動でスクリプトを実行する場合は画面にエラーが表示されそうなのでわかりそうですが、
　トリガーで実行している時にこの制限に掛かっていることは　try {} catch() {} では取得できるものでしょうか？
　時間を超えているので打ち切られる気がするもので。

ご存知の方がおられたら教えていただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

私もちょうど同じ悩みがあったので、知っている範囲で回答します。

1:メールの残クオータであれば下記で確認できます
MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
またGoogleのAPIを使用していればGCPのAPIコンソールで利用状況を確認できます。

2:記憶曖昧ですが、15時ごろ(おそらくPST0時)でリセットされてました
3:検証してないのでわかりません。。